# Caching must be implemented at view level, in models or in serializers in Django

Tags: python, django, caching

I have a web application purely based on REST API using Django Rest Framework. I have seen that at most of the places the response for my APIs is not changing or not changing frequently, so I'm thinking to cache such API's and for that, I'm using https://pypi.org/project/redis/ package. So my question here is what could be the better way to implement caching, it should be at the view level, at the model level, or in the serializer. How it could be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cache for APIview and ViewSets with decorators like `cache_page`.

**NOTE: The cache_page decorator only caches the GET and HEAD responses with status 200.**

Ex:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    # Cache requested url for each user for 2 hours
    @method_decorator(cache_page(60*60*2))
    def list(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'user_feed': request.user.get_user_feed()
        }
        return Response(content)
```

**Or**

```
class PostView(APIView):

    # Cache page for the requested url
    @method_decorator(cache_page(60*60*2))
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'title': 'Post title',
            'body': 'Post content'
        }
        return Response(content)
```

[*DRF cache docs.*](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/caching/)

**settings.py:**

```
# Enable memcache
# https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcache#using_memcache_from_python
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django_pylibmc.memcached.PyLibMCCache'
    }
}
```

If you want store just result of a method or a query and store for furture requests, you can just define a key for it and set that result to that key with `cache.set(cache_key, result, expire_time)` and then get it(`cache.get(cache_key)`) whenever you want.
Remember you should define a cache backend for your results.Proper and better solution is to use message brokers like redis or memcached to store cache.based on your needs.

**//Updated//**

check if data is already cashed or not.

```
    class WeatherView(APIView):
        def get(self):
            if(cache.get('weatherdata') == None):
                url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=' + '...';
                serialized_data = urlopen(url).read()
                data = json.loads(serialized_data)
                print(data)
    
                cache.set('weatherdata', data, 3600)
            else:
                data = cache.get('weatherdata')
    
            serializer_class = WeatherSerializer(data)
    
            responseJSON = JSONRenderer().render(serializer_class.data)
    
            return Response(responseJSON)
```

Comment: I don't want to cache the whole APIView, I just want to cache the method response, but where to cache, is priority

Comment: Here only get method is cached not whole APIView cached.[How to set cached in response headers?](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#standard-httpresponse-attributes)